# Adding Hyperlinks Through Code To Excel

Tags: c#, hyperlink

I am using this C# procedure that will add hyperlinks to column G of a workbook.  It works in 99% of the cases, but if the value in column A has an `'` in it then the syntax does not add a valid hyperlink.  I thought I had accounted for special characters in my line of code that reads

```
if (cellVal == "*,*" 
|| cellVal == "*'*" 
|| cellVal == "*&*" 
|| cellVal == "*-*" 
|| cellVal == "*.*")
```

However, when stepping through the code it **ALWAYS** goes to the `else` block and I am not sure why.  For example, the below values clearly have an `'` in them, but again the code just hits the `else` block

> Joe's Garage
>   Jack's Burger Shack
>   
> Larry's Giant Shake
>   
> Bob's Brews

What do I need to alter in this syntax so that the hyperlink is created in the proper manner?

```
public static void AddHyperlinksToExcel()
{
   long lr, i;
   string cellVal;
   WS = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
   lr = WS.Cells[WS.Rows.Count, 2].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
        for (i = 2; i <= lr; i++)
        {
            Object Anchor = WS.Cells[i, 7];
            Object TextToDisplay = Convert.ToString(WS.Cells[i, 9]);
            cellVal = WS.Cells[i, 1].Value;
            rangeToHoldHyperlink = WS.Range["G" + i];
            if (cellVal == "*,*" || cellVal == "*'*" || cellVal == "*&*" || cellVal == "*-*" || cellVal == "*.*")
            {
                xlApp.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor, "", "'" + cellVal + "'!A1", "", TextToDisplay);
            }
            else
            {
                xlApp.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor, "", "'" + cellVal + "'!A1", "", TextToDisplay);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the data type of cellVal ? I guess its not a pure .net string - you seem to be doing pattern matching on it which is not a feature of a .net string, so I guess its an Excel data type of some kind ?

Comment: cellVal is a text string, it is the value of Column A of an Excel Worksheet..  It is column A of the worksheet and contains text values with examples listed in my post.  if I right click on the cell and go to format cell under the Number tab it is listed as "General"

Comment: Sorry - it didn't really answer my query; cellVal can't be a System.String data type as defined in .net since it doesn't support wildcard matches using "==" so it has to be a Excel specified data type. Put a breakpoint on the code and tell my what data type cellValue variable is. Once we know that we can look up the docs on what "==" is valid to match on. I greatly suspect there is some special handling required for some escaped characters.

Comment: How do I get the data type?  I stepped through code and when I hover over it, it just gives me the value of the cell (Joe's Garage)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on it (you seem to have done that) then open the Debug Immediate window and type "cellVal.GetType().Name" and press return.

Comment: When I add the breakpoint and add cellVal.GetType().Name to the Immediate window and hit enter this is what is shown....cellVal.GetType().Name
"String"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cellVal is a System.String your code will not work in the way you expect..net does not support wildcard matching using "==". You should replace `cellValue == '*&*'` etc with `cellValue.Contains("&")`

Comment: Do I still need to use the `*` when using `Contains("'")`?  Reason I ask is I just modified my code to `if (cellVal.Contains("&") || cellVal.Contains(",") || cellVal.Contains("'") || cellVal.Contains("-") || cellVal.Contains("."))` and I got the same outcome as before.

Comment: No - as I said, .net strings do not use wildcards for matching. Put a break point on your "If" statement, then use the immediate window again. Type in "cellValue" and press return. We'd expect to see the value of the cell. If its not what you expect then there is your problem. If it is what you expect i.e. "BellHop&ByDay" then if you enter " cellValue.Contains('&') " it will return True.

Comment: That was it exactly!  Not sure what was going on, I closed my project, re-opened, cleaned the solution, then build it, started it, and BAM!  Ran exactly as you described above.  Thank you for helping out on this!

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from @PhillipH will solve all the Or cases **Except** an apastrophe.  Reason being, Excel converts the apastrophe to double quotes.  For example, in Excel 2016 I created a worksheet called `Joe's Garage` and began recording a macro.  The steps I followed was

> 1) Click Insert from the ribbon
>   2) Select Hyperlink from the ribbon
>   
> 3) On the left of the options that display click 'Place in this document'
>   
> 4) Select the worksheet name you would like to link to
>   
> Note -- If you look at your worksheet name you are trying to link to it has been altered to `'Joe''s Garage'`
>   
> 5) Click Ok

Now you have a fully functioning hyperlink with value(s) that have apostrophe in them.

This is not the C# syntax, but this is what the Excel VBA presented from the Macro recorder, which illustrates the same as the steps above

```
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'Joe''s Garage'!A1", TextToDisplay:="Link To Joe's Garage"
```